# AutoLayout (Y-Constraints for different iPhones)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

The problem I'm having is that the y-size of the iPhone 4 is much smaller than the y-size of the iPhone 5 & 6(+).

If I want to support both devices I can use almost only half of the screen of the iPhone 6(+) because if I use the whole screen and add y-constraints to the top and bottom it does not work for the iPhone 4 since the constraint lengths are way too big.

How can I use the whole screen of the iPhone 6 and similarily use the full screen of the iPhone 4? Is there anything I'm missing?

I watched a tutorial but the tutor only uses center-y as constraint.

Comment: may you share a screen of what you want to realize?

Comment: You can use aspect ratio constraints, for having proportional heights . Also it is not possible to help you with this for someone without the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. why is it necessary to set a bottom y-constraint?
2. otherwise, you could put everything inside a scrollview (with scroll enabled and with all the y-constraints you want at top and bottom between the scroll view and the main view), and inside the scroll view you can put the previous top and bottom y-constraints
3. if you use size-classes, you should be able to create a specific layout for iPhone 4 and another one for iPhone 5-6+

Comment: I think ScrollView is the way to go since what I want to put on the display doesn't fit the iPhone 4 screen. Must not upload of this project. Maybe I create a quick test project later and provide screenshots of what I meant if ScrollView doesn't do the trick